# Setting an HTTPS EndPoint in Code?

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm defining a Service Reference in code using the following:

```
EndpointAddress NewEndPoint = 
new EndpointAddress("http://example.com/someservice.asmx");

sr_SomeService.SomeServiceSoapClient _SomeService = 
new sr_SomeService.SomeServiceSoapClient(
new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding(), NewEndPoint);
```

When I use an EndPoint with HTTP the above code works however when I try an HTTPS address I get the following error:
**The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.
Parameter name: via**

How do I use an HHTPS EndPoint?

Comment: I understand that however I'm not sure how to work with the BasicHttpSecurity option.

Comment: See [`BasicHttpsBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpsbinding.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code for the answer :)

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
EndpointAddress NewEndPoint = 
new EndpointAddress("https://example.com/someservice.asmx");

sr_SomeService.SomeServiceSoapClient _SomeService = 
new sr_SomeService.SomeServiceSoapClient(binding, NewEndPoint);
```

Thanks for the pointers.